# If $|z|=1$ then $|f(z)|>2$ and $f(0)=1$ Then $f$ must have a zero in the unit disc.

Tags: complex-analysis

> Suppose $f\in \mathcal{H}(U)$, $U$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{C}$ containing closed unit disc. $|f(z)|>2$ if $|z|=1$ and $f(0)=1$. Then $f$ have a zero in the unit disc.

Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since

$\vert f(z) \vert > 2 \tag 1$

for $\vert z \vert = 1$, $f(z)$ has no zero on the unit circle.  Suppose

$f(z) \ne 0 \tag 2$

for all $z \in D$, where $D$ is the open unit disk.  Then

$\dfrac{1}{f(z)} \in H(D), \tag 3$

and

$\vert \dfrac{1}{f(z)} \vert = \dfrac{1}{\vert f(z) \vert} < \dfrac{1}{2} \tag 4$

when $\vert z \vert = 1$.  Also,

$\vert \dfrac{1}{f(0)} \vert = 1, \tag 5$

since $f(0) = 1$.  (4) and (5) together contradict the maximum modulus principle, since the maximum of $\vert 1 / f(z) \vert$ over $\bar D$ must occur on the circle $z = 1$.  By (4), said maximum is less than $1/2$, but again, $1 / \vert f(0) \vert = 1$, so . . . $f(z) \ne 0$ for $z \in \bar D$.